# VBA loop through range of cells fails

Tags: vba, excel

For some reason, the code below fails on the second line with run-time error '1004' stating "Method 'Intersect' of object '_Application' failed" and on some occasions where I have tried to amend the code it produces a '_Global' failure. The stranger thing is that I have played with various versions of this code and sometimes after many changes during debug mode I retried this form and then it runs. If I then try to rerun the code it fails again.

---

rng1 is a set of cells from the same column, rng2 is a set of cells over multiple columns with the same rows as rng1

e.g. rng1 = {A2:A10},
     rng2 = {D2:H10}

The instructions saves the values of cells from within a single row of rng2 with respect to an individual entry in rng1 into an array. I have checked that the ranges are on the same sheet, valid and (where named) are referencing the correct cells.

```
For Each c In Range("rng1").Cells

        For Each d In Application.Intersect(Rows(c.Row), Range("rng2")).Cells

            *some instructions here*

        Next d

Next c
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead, the only time your code caused errors for me was when the intersection ended up being empty.

```
Dim c As Range, d As Range
Dim rng As Range

For Each c In Range("test1")
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Rows(c.Row), Range("test2"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        '' Empty intersection ''
        Debug.Print "Empty"
    Else
        For Each d In rng
            '' some instructions here ''
            Debug.Print d.Address
        Next d
    End If
Next c
```

Of course you should probably also be prefixing your `Range` and `Rows` with the sheet, e.g:

```
Sheet1.Rows
```

and

```
Sheet1.Range("test1")
```

etcetera...

Comment: Regarding the comment in the question about running it and it works then re-running it and it doesn't, I think your last comment is on the mark. It would fail to work if you had a different sheet selected when you ran it.

Comment: I think that's probably the issue... Remember folks: ALWAYS fully qualify everything! `Range(...)` is **evil**

Comment: @kaben If my answer has helped resolve your problem, please consider accepting it as the answer to your question. This will also help others with the same/similar problem to find an answer more easily.